# Can you check to see if an IBM MQ topic is up and available through a Java application before attempting to create a connection?

Tags: ibm-mq

I would like to add some conditional logic to our Java application code for attempting to create a JMS Topic Connection. I have seen problems in the past stemming from attempting to create a connection when the MQ server had been restarted or was currently down. One improvement I added was to check for the quiescent state, and another was to increase the timer before attempting reconnection to our durable topic queue.

Is there a way to confirm with the MQ server/topic/channel that it is up and running and a connection request can safely be made?

Comment: You should receive an error if you attempt to connect and the queue manager is down.   If you were already connected then it went down you would receive a different error during the next operation.   If this is a standalone app then you can enable auto reconnect to cover the second case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to confirm that a queue manager (and the channel you are using to connect to the queue manager) is up and running is to attempt to connect to it.

If your connection attempt fails, you will get an MQ Reason code telling you exactly why. This is a much better way to confirm than any administrative command, because it also confirms that your application, and it's security context is correct and able to connect to the queue manager. It is completely possible to have an up-and-running queue manager but an application that is not yet correctly configured to use it. So connect from the application and if it works, the queue manager is up-and-running.

Your comment about having an increased timer before attempting to reconnect after a failure is well made. It doesn't help anyone if you hammer the queue manager with lots of repeated and close together connection attempts until it is ready to accept your connection, but still anything that is going to test the availability of the queue manager needs to ultimately connect to it, so very simply, just connect.

Comment: It makes sense that handling the exceptions returned by MQ in the reconnect logic would be the best way to go. I'm glad that the attempt to increase the timer was a good practice.   Thank you.